# Routing issue with Symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony, xampp

I'm trying to access through localhost (Xampp) the index file from the folder in a Symfony project. Although i'm writing the following path it cannot find the page: http://localhost/google_analytics_app/consolytics-app/analytics/
[tree-folder-structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgjrh.jpg)

Following the instructions i use the base file in my index.html.twig file under the folder viwes/analytics/

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
```

and use my own index file under the folder/analytics/index.html.twig.
I also used annotations inside the src/AppBundle/Controller/IndexController.php :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use AppBundle\Library\GoogleAnalytics;
use Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug as dump;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/analytics/index", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {

        ....

  return $this->render('index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

When type the path it shows 404 error message. Can someone help with this routing issue? In my composer.json file:

```
"require": {
"twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
},
```

Comment: Didn't You forget register routes in routing.yml  file ?

Comment: If you declare your route as `/analytics/index` you should call the same url (you forgot `/index` part)  
`http://localhost/google_analytics_app/consolytics-app/analytics/index`

Comment: @zalex But thats what the anottation does ? I mean you don't have to register to the routing file, only in the controller..  but after also trying in the routing.yml file i still have the same issue:                                                                      
   `index:
    resource: app/Resources/views/analytics/index.html
    prefix: /analytics/index`   @goto I have also tried that but still the same .

Comment: You MUST register your routes. 
 https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/routing.html#loading-routes

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that You didn't register your routings in routing.yml file.

You have to understand that annotations are describe routes, but your router component don't now anything about your routes before You register that one in routing.yml file. From this file (v3.4) router gets your routes.

https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/best_practices/controllers.html#routing-configuration

```
# app/config/routing.yml
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type:     annotation
```

Pay attantion for type parameter. Annotation says to router that your routes are actually annotations :)

Answer (score -1):

Your param for the render-method is wrong. It has to be return 
`$this->render('views/analytics/index.html.twig');`